# How to create a jagged array using user input, then display users input and sum C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, user-input, jagged-arrays

[image]Ok I got the arrays to have a fixed number to display and sum but what I'm trying to do is have the user fill all three arrays and then display them with there sum in one label if possible. Here is what I have. I have looked for information on this on Google with some results but not for C#. The reason I'm asking this question is to better myself, I have already accomplished what I was supposed to do. I would like to know how a user would create there own array and then have it displayed with their sum.  Please help and I appreciate any help. Please go easy on me. I still am a beginner. If you don't understand what I'm trying to ask, please allow me to elaborate.

The Image is an example of what i want the user to be able to do in order to populate the arrays.

Here is the code for that. Im trying to basically combine them in a way the user can build the array rather then have the array already populated.

```
private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Nmbrs[x] = Convert.ToInt32(UsrInputBox.Text);
 UsrInputBox.ResetText();
 ++x;
 if (x == Nmbrs.Length)
 GetSmlLrg();
}

//Method
void GetSmlLrg()
{
 int Sml = Nmbrs[0];
 int Lrg = Nmbrs[0];
 for (x = 1; x < Nmbrs.Length; ++x)
 {
  if (Nmbrs[x] < Sml)
  Sml = Nmbrs[x];
  if (Nmbrs[x] > Lrg)
  Lrg = Nmbrs[x];
 }
```

My code im trying to incorporate the ability to have the user populate the array.

```
int[] Nmbr1 = { 9, 5, 3, 9, 8 };
int[] Nmbr2 = { 24, 48, 90, 36, 4, 9, 2, 7 };
int[] Nmbr3 = { 84,97,63,48,12,789,2,5,8,2,54,8,6 };

//Main Button
private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 GetSum(Nmbr1);
 GetSum(Nmbr2);
 GetSum(Nmbr3);
}

//Method
public void GetSum(int[]Array)
{
 int Total = 0;
 for (int x = 0; x < Array.Length; ++x)
 {
  if (x == 0)
  Output.Text += "\n";
  Output.Text += " " + Array[x];
  Total += Array[x];
 }
 Output.Text += "\nThe total is - " + Total + "\n"+"----------------------------------
 ------";
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to write the input loop? Or do you want user defined arrays (which should actually be lists IMO).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I believe so. I want to be able to have the user enter the there numbers one at a time in the Uinputbox.text. I know I need to set the array amount and I would need it to be jagged amounts with at least three different arrays.

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure what exactly your question is...is it about how to get the user's input into the arrays? If so, your form could have 3 text boxes, then in Submit_Click you would read them and put the contents into the array (perhaps assuming they entered comma-separated values, e.g. "1,2,3,4,5", you would split the string on the comma, use int.Parse() on each and populate your integer arrays.

Comment: @BradDivine I'm trying to have the user input there number in the textbox then hit submit which will repeat the number of times the for each array. then display all three arrays and the sum with the output.text label.

Comment: Ok. Working directly with arrays is a little bit of a pain because they are static; if it is possible to use some other data structure to capture the user's input first (say, a List<string> or List<int>) you could then create and populate your int arrays after the user is finished entering the numbers.

Comment: How do you know when the array terminates? If they are just clicking submit a bunch of times, it seems unlikely this would work. Perhaps you could post a screenshot of your UI?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET agreed, this is an interface question. Does the user or program decide how many arrays to create? Does the user or program decide how many items are in each array? The answers to those two questions will go a long way to figuring out the best way to capture the input.

Comment: @BradleyDotNEt I have updated the question with the screenshot and the code that i am trying to incorporate.

Comment: @BradDivine I have updated the question with the screenshot and the code that i am trying to incorporate.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you need to modify your UI a bit.

You need your text box, submit button, and a new "Calculate" button. The calculate button indicates that input is complete, and then displays the result.

The code would look something like:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
private void Submit_Click(...)
{
   numbers.Add(int.Parse(UsrInputBox.Text));
}

private void Calculate_Click(...)
{
   int smallest = numbers.Min();
   int largest = numbers.Max();

   //Display code
}
```

Note that I use a `List<T>`, because you don't use arrays when the size is not known at compile-time. I also take advantage of the LINQ `Min` and `Max` functions to make the search easier. You probably haven't learned about them yet, but the LINQ extensions are very powerful tools in C#.

Let me know if this helps or if you have questions. This example doesn't have the 3 arrays you did, but you're UI doesn't show them either. If you need that kind of behavior you'll just run the above code in some sort of loop. If you provide more details I can try and flesh it out a bit for you.